# How to Stop MS Access From Undesired Cascading Delete?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

When I delete a record from one Microsoft Access table, it deletes the corresponding record in another table. I need to stop that.

1. Table 'items' has ID (the key), item_name, and some other fields.
2. Table 'special_order_item' has 'item' (the key), quantity, and some other fields.
3. special_order_item.item is an Access Lookup field, with Row Source: `ID, item_name FROM items;`

There is no relationship between the tables defined in Access.

The apparent cascaded delete happens only when I use the GUI to select the record in special_order_items and press the Delete key. If I enter and run a SQL delete statement, the record is deleted from 'special_order_items' without impacting 'items'.

It happens only when the Row Source is a SQL query (e.g. a SELECT statement); not when the row source is a table.

My intent is that a special_order_items record must have an 'item' drawn from items. 'items' is my list of things which can be special-ordered. Deleting a special-order should not delete the item from the orderables - just from special-order.

Comment: Any possibility your MS Access file is connecting to a SQL Server instance for the tables?...if so, the foreign key relationships with cascade deletion might be defined there.

Comment: Not a remote database. All the data is in the .accdb. However, new discovery. This happens only when deleting via the GUI. Question text updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Making the Row Source into a read-only query solves it. The easiest way to make a query read-only is to include some computation; the easiest computation is to add 'distinct'.  e.g. I changed

`SELECT ID, item_name FROM items;` to `SELECT DISTINCT ID, item_name from items;`

That made it a read-only query, and selecting + deleting the special_order_items record via the GUI no longer deletes the record from 'items'.